# Making a cli that creates next 13 projects from me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, command-line-interface

I have a particular use case in which what I want is to have some kind of CLI that takes primary and secondary colors from the user and, based on those colors, bootstraps the next 13 projects that have those colors defined in the tailwind config file. I do not know where to start how can I achieve this???

Comment: you can start with simple node project or a bash file...

Comment: ok. Some more info will be much appreciated. like how to take inputs from the user and how to create next js project like how to run the create-next-app and answer the question that next js asks from you????